# if you short sell? And Right issue has taken place, so Does Right issue has negative positions in Portfolio or not?

Tags: equities, portfolio-management, finance

I  am searching for exact accounting example of Stock right position in Portfolio when someone is short sell.

Searched a lot over Google, contacted local Brokers as well..Didn't get any response.

Please help to understand the secanrio with examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you shortsell a stock, then you are short all the rights (no pun intended) that a stockholder has including dividends, spinoff shares, rights, warrants, whatever.  You will owe the rights as well.

Comment: Agreed..let me change the question to...Can I short sell Rights?

Comment: yes - the rights are tradable instruments for a period of time and can be shorted if you can secure the borrow.

Comment: So the position in Portfolio can be negative for a time being..once covered all equal.

Comment: yup.  Also imagine shortselling stock X which spins off stock Y.  after the spinoff, you are still short the residual of stock X and short the appropriate units of stock Y.  TO close your position, you need to buy back both.  The rights issue is similar to this situation.